Fields are returned as null in MongoDB Aggregation pagination with Spring Data Mongo
I am implementing pagination in a Spring Data Mongo project using MongoDB Aggregation. While the data is retrieved, the fields in the result are all returned as null, and I am struggling to understand why.
Environment:

Spring Boot 3.1.4
Spring Data MongoDB 4.1.4
MongoDB

Issue Description:
Data is successfully stored in MongoDB, and I have set up pagination using the aggregation framework. However, the fields in the retrieved objects are all null in the results.
Code Details:
Label Class
@Document(collection = "labels")
public class Label extends BaseDocument {
    private LabelType type;
    private String path;
    private ObjectId datasetId;
    private String annotations;
    // Constructors, getters, setters...
}

Repository Code
@Repository
public class LabelRepositoryCustomImpl implements LabelRepositoryCustom {
    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
    @Override
    public Page<Label> findAllWithPagination(Pageable pageable, ObjectId datasetId) {
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("datasetId").is(datasetId)),
            Aggregation.sort(pageable.getSort()),
            Aggregation.facet(
                Aggregation.count().as("totalCount"),
                Aggregation.skip((long) pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize()),
                Aggregation.limit(pageable.getPageSize())
            ).as("metadata")
        );
        AggregationResults<Label> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "labels", Label.class);
        List<Label> labels = results.getMappedResults();
        return PageableExecutionUtils.getPage(labels, pageable, labels::size);
    }
}

Mongo Aggregation Query
{ 
    "aggregate" : "labels", 
    "pipeline" : [
        { "$match" : { "datasetId" : { "$oid" : "672ac21827cf3f529bbb5a57"}}}, 
        { "$sort" : { "createdAt" : -1}}, 
        { "$facet" : { 
            "metadata" : [
                { "$count" : "totalCount"}, 
                { "$skip" : 0}, 
                { "$limit" : 10}
            ]
        }}
    ]
}

Problem:

Although the aggregation pipeline finds matching data, all fields in the Label object are returned as null.
The Label class has a private default constructor, @Document annotation, and field types that match MongoDB's data types.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Are you able to run the same aggregation query in the MongoDB shell or Compass?

the problem seems that your class Label doesn't match output query. Your query return a structure like this:
{
  metadata: [
  { totalCount: 100 }
  ]
}

and your class have a structure like this:
{
  type: ""
  path: ""
  datasetId: ""
  annotations: ""
}

So you are losing all prev fields of documents because $facet:

Processes multiple aggregation pipelines within a single stage on the same set of input documents. Each sub-pipeline has its own field in the output document where its results are stored as an array of documents.

Source: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.1/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/
Can I suggest to use MongoRepository without use MongoTemplate?
Example like this:
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;

public interface LabelRepository extends MongoRepository<Label, ObjectId> {
    
    @Query("{ 'datasetId': ?0 }")
    Page<Label> findByDatasetId(ObjectId datasetId, Pageable pageable);
}

This will return a Page automatically.
If you want to use Aggregation with mongoTemplate you must run 2 query (one count and one for page) like this:
@Repository
public class LabelRepositoryCustomImpl implements LabelRepositoryCustom {
    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    
    @Autowired
    public LabelRepositoryCustomImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Page<Label> findAllWithPagination(Pageable pageable, ObjectId datasetId) {
        // Conteggio totale dei documenti
        long total = countByDatasetId(datasetId);
        
        // Aggregazione per la paginazione
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("datasetId").is(datasetId)),
            Aggregation.sort(pageable.getSort()),
            Aggregation.skip((long) pageable.getPageNumber() * pageable.getPageSize()),
            Aggregation.limit(pageable.getPageSize())
        );
        
        AggregationResults<Label> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "labels", Label.class);
        List<Label> labels = results.getMappedResults();

        return new PageImpl<>(labels, pageable, total);
    }
    
    private long countByDatasetId(ObjectId datasetId) {
        // Aggregazione per il conteggio totale dei documenti
        Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
            Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("datasetId").is(datasetId)),
            Aggregation.count().as("total")
        );
        
        AggregationResults<CountResult> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "labels", CountResult.class);
        CountResult countResult = results.getUniqueMappedResult();
        return countResult != null ? countResult.getTotal() : 0;
    }
    
    static class CountResult {
        private long total;

        public long getTotal() {
            return total;
        }

        public void setTotal(long total) {
            this.total = total;
        }
    }
}

a lot of code lines unnecessary imo.
Hope this will help you

I was working on something else first, but I checked it late. When I ran the test code using Mongo Repository, the expected result was returned. Thanks to you, I was able to resolve this issue. Thank you!
